# Action of automorphism group on Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, finite-groups

I want to know whether an automorphism group of a simple Lie algebra over $GF(2)$, acts transitively on non-zero elements of Lie algebra or not? How can I check this property?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161104/homogeneous-algebras.

Comment: yes. it was clear. I am sorry for asking repetative question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely not.  For example some elements are $\mathrm{ad}$-nilpotent and others are $\mathrm{ad}$-diagonable.

Comment: what do you mean by ad-diagonable?

Comment: @user40491, an element $x$ in the Lie algebra is ad-diagonalizable if the map $y\in g\mapsto [x,y]\in g$ is diagonalizable.